# How to modify base_properties in Plone custom skin

Tags: css, plone, skins

I want to change some of the built-in styles contained in a Plone 4 installation, and a reading of the docs tells me that the best way to do this is to copy the base_properties.props file to SOMEWHERE in the file tree, and then to modify it.

A thorough search of this Plone system shows two base_properties.props files, neither of them in the file tree of my custom skin. So, I guess the first problem is to figure out WHICH of these files is active. I am not sure - how to tell easily?

The next problem is WHERE to copy this file into my custom skin file tree. The existing folders are: Skins\custom_images, Skins\custom_js, Skins\custom_styles, Skins\custom_templates. Should the base_properties file then go in the Skins\ root?

I want to change the defaults for things like evenRowBackgroundColor - without modifying the main base_properties file, as I gather that will make site maintenance a bit more difficult down the road.

Sorry if this is rudimentary, but I find myself spending lots of time figuring out how Plone works - and not too much time actually doing any styling...

Answer (score 5):

In a default Plone 4 installation neither of the base_properties.props files is active, because the default "Sunburst" theme doesn't use base properties.

If you're using the Classic theme, then you want to copy base_properties.props from the classic_styles skin layer in the plonetheme.classic egg.

As for the question of which folder to copy into, I would probably put it in custom_styles, since it is related to the styles applied. It doesn't really matter though as long as these custom skin layers are ordered above the layer that you are copying the file from. To check on the order of the layers, go to portal_skins in the ZMI and click on the Properties tab. This lists the layers of each skin, in order of precedence.

Answer (score 2):

As David Glick says:"To check on the order of the layers, go to portal_skins in the ZMI and click on the Properties tab. This lists the layers of each skin, in order of precedence."

But you want to select the default skin for which you are using basic properties and save it at the bottom. I couldn't get the Sumburst Theme to work so I went classic and used that as default and modified it's basic properties.

Answer (score 0):

What are the full paths of the files that you found? That should give you a clue as to which one you should use.

skins/custom_styles is the preferred location although all of them will work.